# How to detect touch events in Rectangle canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, graphics, rect

I am drawing multiple rectangle in my canvas .I can drag and drop and scale around the screen.Everything  works fine.When i rotate the rectangle at angle.its not working.Please help me with this..

[image]

I am using this formula to detect the touch event

```
 if ( xTouch >= CenterX && xTouch < (CenterX + width)
                && yTouch >= CenterY && yTouch < (CenterY+ height)){
     //some code
}
```

Now when I rotate the canvas using this base point to 50 degress. How can i detect the touch event.
  Any help would be appreciated

```
 canvas.rotate(50.0,CenterX,CenterY)
```